# SyntaxError: missing ; before statement in Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, syntax

This is the code concerned:

```
    var membre = '<?= $_SESSION['login'] ?>';
```

I get this error when I check the Firebug console:
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement in Javascript

And the Javascript doesn't execute itself. 
What's weird is that this used to work, and it also works in local, without an issue.

Do you know why? Or is there another way to get the 'login' SESSION in a Javascript variable?

Thanks

Comment: What is the content of `$_SESSION['login']`? Are you sure the PHP is being evaluated? Did you try to View Source? Does your server config allow short tags, or are you using PHP 5.4?

Comment: Does your login session var contain a single quote?

Comment: @Druska: incorrect. PHP will be evaluated before JavaScript.

Comment: Could you show what the server returns for that line?

Comment: you use single quotes inside of your string, that also uses single quotes: try using double quotes for the outer quotes: `"<?= $_SESSION['login'] ?>"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not dump PHP variables into JavaScript strings like that. There is a mechanism already in place:

```
var membre = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['login']) ?>;
```

This will automatically add quotes and escape any problematic characters in a string. It can also be used for numbers and booleans (passed raw), and even arrays (converted to literals).

Answer (score 0):

Your line of code should be either this (1):

```
// double quotes on the outside and single quotes on the inside or vice versa
var membre = "<?= $_SESSION['login'] ?>";
```

or this (2):

```
var membre = '<?= $_SESSION[' + login + '] ?>';
```

This depends on if you want to access a property with the name "login" (1) or if you want to access a property with the content of a javascript variable named "login" (2).

Anyway, your code (`var membre = '<?= $_SESSION['login'] ?>';`) is actually two separated string with the name "login" in the middle. So javascript wants to assign the string `"<?= $_SESSION["` to the variable `membre` and expects a semicolon after that. But instead of a semicolon it finds the word "login", which it thinks is a different statement. That is why you get the error "missing ; before statement".

**EDIT**

As Felix Kling pointed out, I was an the wrong path here, since the PHP code inside `<?= ... ?>` is evaluated first (see his comment below). So, the inner single quotes are not the issue here.

Comment: The single quotes are not a problem, at this stage at least. PHP does not care what is around `<?= $_SESSION['login'] ?>`. It might look strange, but since the whole code is evaluated in two phases, it's not a problem. The `<?= ... ?>` part is first evaluated by PHP and the output might be something like `var membre = 'foo';`, which does not pose a problem in JavaScript. It's only a problem if the output generated by PHP contains a (single) quotation mark.

Comment: I see. I guess you're right, how could I miss that!? I completely ignored that this is PHP. I answered it in the context of pure JavaScript.

Comment: The syntax highlighting in the question certainly does not help to make this clearer ;) It's understandable to be confused by that.

Comment: Wait wait wait, what? "property withthe [name from] a javascript variable"? What is this sorcery?